# Hashmap return null value issue

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I have two models the first one is cartItem model that have HashMap < String, ProductOption>, ProductOption is the second model.

First Model :

```
public class CartItem extends BaseObservable implements Serializable {
  ...
HashMap<String, ProductOption> options;
  ...
@Ignore
public HashMap<String, ProductOption> getOptions() {
    return options;
}

@Ignore
public void setOptions(HashMap<String, ProductOption> options) {
    this.options = options;
}

}
```

Second Model :

```
public class ProductOption implements Parcelable {
    String optionId;
    String optionKey;
    String optionValue;}
```

when I try to set a list of cart item to the recyclerview adapter all cartitem model items copy but options copy as null

```
mViewModel.getCartItems().observe(this,cartItems -> {
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) return;
        if (cartItems ==null ) return;


        cartItemList = cartItems;
        cartAdapter.setCartItemList(cartItems);


    });
```

thank you for help.

Comment: You never call setOptions in this code...

Comment: no need for using setOptions 
cartItemList = cartItems; 
this line copy all the list of cart items

Comment: It doesn't copy anything. It reassigns the variable `cartItemList`, which you also don't show in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason that makes options null is that I loop options variable by iterator and uses it.remove() this way of looping remove options on cartItemList

```
 if (cartItemList.get(i).getOptions() != null){
            HashMap<String, ProductOption> optionHashMap = cartItemList.get(i).getOptions();
            Iterator it = optionHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
            double optionPrice = 0;
            while (it.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                optionPrice += Double.valueOf(((ProductOption)pair.getValue()).getOptionValue());
                it.remove();
            }

            price = price + optionPrice;

        }
```